# Strange EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION using route-me on iPod

Tags: iphone, ipod, route-me

I'm getting some really strange EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION only on iPod Touches using route-me. route-me is a library that's in my project.

Here are the details. I'm initWithFrame a Mapview.

```
mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
```

I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION inside initWithFrame for RMMapView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{ //DEBUGGER STOPS HERE FOR SOME REASON
    LogMethod();
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self performInitialSetup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The debugger just stops on the first {. What's even more strange is that when I view the contents of "frame" instead of being 0,0 for x,and y they are: x = 4.65449901e-10 and y = 3.5698779e-40.

What is going on here? This works fine on any other device.

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on here? I have a feeling it's some project setting that's causing me this. I don't see how the code can be an issue here.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Hopefully this is helpful to others:

As I suspected the route-me project settings were incorrect. First I had to change the project to use the same iOS SDK as my main project. I also had to tell it to build ARM6 ARM7 (Standard). It was building only ARM7 (Optimized).